# click event on a iframe wrapped element

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I may be losing my mind..

I have a div element which is holding an IFRAME. I registered a click event using javascript. That click event is not working when I am on IFRAME (*grey region*) but when I am clicking outside region of IFRAME (*blue region*), the click event is working fine.

What should I do to make this click event work even on IFRAME?

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4T3t/)

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var main = document.getElementById('main');
main.onclick = function () {
    alert('hello');
}
```

PS: **IFRAME is generating dynamically from a plugin, I can't access this code**

Comment: is the iframe generated pointing to an url in your domain?

Comment: Iframe is a different context and new HTML, it won't pass the click to div parent

Comment: @fmodos anyways to solve this issue?

Comment: Does the user have to interact with the iframe? Otherwise you could add an overlay, like [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyUNy/).

Comment: If the iframe isn't on your domain, you can't listen for events occurring within it - it's the normal sandbox model. If it is, you may attach a handler on `iframe.contentWindow.document`

Comment: @RazvanCaliman but the parent container is on my domain right? and I am trying to register a click event on parent container but not the iframe which is from other domain. Anyway, I will try you suggestion..

Comment: When you click on the iframe it will register the event and trap it within that window context. Regardless of where the iframe is loaded from, the event will never bubble up to the container.

Comment: @RazvanCaliman Thanks for explaining clearly.. this worked flawlessly :)

Comment: So you added the handler on the iframe's contentWindow.document?

Comment: @RazvanCaliman yes.. and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

You can add [`pointer-events: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to iFrame's CSS - this way it will not capture clicks. Supported in FF, Safari, Chrome, Opera and IE11+.

Modify your fiddle:

```
iframe {
    pointer-events:none;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

[New fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R3tep/Q4T3t/1/)

Please note user will not be able to interact with iFrame this way.